How to get "supportedAbis" on android browser
How can i get at least one supported ABI of android device through website on android browser?
I just want supported ABI name like (arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a, x86-64) of android device through website programmatically.
Is it possible, if so how can I achieve this.

question is not related to Flutter as in the tags
